# Rails App Painfully Slow to Load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, server

I have a couple of free tier rails apps running on heroku which run really well and I have no problems with.

But this one

kearns.herokuapp.com

is so slow to load! The dyno doesn't sleep as i'm pinging it every few minutes.

If anyone had time could they give it a quick visit and see what they think it might be? Would really appreciate it!

CSS

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";

// Set the correct sprite paths
@iconSpritePath: image-url("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png");
@iconWhiteSpritePath: image-url("twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");

// Set the Font Awesome (Font Awesome is default. You can disable by commenting below lines)
@fontAwesomeEotPath: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot");
@fontAwesomeEotPath_iefix: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix");
@fontAwesomeWoffPath: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.woff");
@fontAwesomeTtfPath: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
@fontAwesomeSvgPath: font-url("fontawesome-webfont.svg#fontawesomeregular");

// Font Awesome
@import "fontawesome/font-awesome";

// Glyphicons
//@import "twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons.less";

// Your custom LESS stylesheets goes here
//
// Since bootstrap was imported above you have access to its mixins which
// you may use and inherit here
//
// If you'd like to override bootstrap's own variables, you can do so here as well
// See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html#variables for their names and documentation
//
// Example:
// @link-color: #ff0000;



p.navbar-text a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}
#phone a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
}

#overflow {
    overflow:hidden;
}

html, body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

#welcome_container {
    overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom:40px;
}

.jumbotron {

    position:relative;
    top:-320px;
    background:transparent;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    margin-bottom:0;
    padding-bottom:0px;

}
.jumbotron h1 {
    position:relative;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}
span {
    color:#F9DF31;
    color:#FAED49;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-style:italic;

        }

.jumbotron p {
    margin-bottom:35px;

}

.test {

    position:relative;
    top:-320px;
    background:transparent;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;
    margin-bottom:0;
    padding-bottom:0px;
}
.test h1 {
    position:relative;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.test p {
    margin-bottom:35px;
    margin-top:25px;;
}


#about_container {
    margin-top:70px;
}
#map_container {
    background:#fff;
}


// Images

#home_image {
    margin-top:40px;
}
.img-polaroid {
    margin-top: 80px;
}

// ------


#block {
    height:50px;
}

#middle {



    padding-bottom:60px;
    padding-top:30px;
}


/* 
-----------------------------
Navbar
-----------------------------
*/   

.navbar-default {
    background:#023249;
    border-color:#008AE6;
    border-color:#fff;
  }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: "Libre Baskerville", sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    color:#CAFF42;
    color:#F9DF31;
    color:#FAED49;


}
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:2em;
    color:#FAED49;
    font-family:Tahoma;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover {
    color:#FAED49;
    color:#FAED49;
}

.navbar-text {
    font-size:13px;
    padding-top:3px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-family:helvetica;
    color:#fff;
}
p.navbar-text a {
    color:#fff;
}
p.navbar-text a:hover {
    color:#CAFF42;
    background:#023249;
    color:#F9DF31;
    color:#FAED49;
}
p.navbar-text {
    color:#fff;
}





// Home Page


.background-image {
    height:525px;
    background-image:asset-data-url("good.jpg");
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 1500px 525px;
    text-align:center;

    background-color:#fff;

}

@media screen and (min-width: 1550px) {

    .background-image {
    background-size: 100% 525px;
    }
}

#welcome_container {

    padding-top:30px;
}

#text_block {
    height:300px;
    background:#000;
    margin-top:150px;
    opacity:0.5;
}

#image_row {
background:#064780;
background:#F6FAFB;
background:#49708A;
}








// Contact & Map

#map {
    height:400px;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    background:gray;
}








// Headings

h3.center-text {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:40px;
}
h3.home {
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff;


}



// Paragraphs

p.welcome-text { 
    color: #333; 
    font-size: 19px; 
    font-family: "Libre Baskerville", 
    serif; line-height: 40px; 
    text-align: justify; 

    padding-top: 10px; 
}

p.image-text { 
    color: #333; 
    font-size: 18px; 
    font-family: "Libre Baskerville", 
    serif; line-height: 30px; 
    text-align: justify; 

    padding-top: 20px; 
}

p.service-text { 
    color: #333; 
    font-size: 17px; 
    font-family: "Libre Baskerville", 
    serif; line-height: 40px; 
    text-align: justify; 






}



// Misc

.push {
    margin-bottom:50px;
}
#no_line {
    text-decoration:none;
}



// Buttons

.btn btn-primary {
    color:#fff;
}




// Services Page

#service_row_2 {
    margin-top:70px;
    background-color:#E6E6E6;
}
#service_first_para {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
#service_header {
    margin-top:50px;









    background:#F6FAFB;
    background:#064780;
    background:#A0C2DE;
    background:#49708A;




}
#service_heading {
    margin-top:45px;
}
#service_h4 {
    text-align:center;
}

/*
-------------------------
  Catalog Page
-------------------------
*/


#catalog_header {
    margin-top:100px;
    background:#001A29;


}
#catalog_heading {
    margin-top: 45px;
}
#catalog_first_para {
    margin-bottom: 40px;


}
#catalog_h4 {
    margin-top:50px;
}



/*
-------------------------
  About Page
-------------------------
*/

#about_header {
    margin-top:50px;
    background:#023249;
    margin-bottom:40px;
}

#about_div {
    height:500px;

}
#about_div_second {
    margin-top:50px;
}
#staff_heading {
    text-align:right;
}


/* 
-----------------------------
   Footer
-----------------------------
*/   

#footer {

    height:100px;
    background:#fff;



}
#footer h3 {
    color:#fff;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, your `application.css` file (http://kearns.herokuapp.com/assets/application-c515eba896f4bd53f59a05b117a195e0.css right now) is over 16 MB. It looks like you included actual image file there - it should only have the image's url.

Comment: I know! But the only reference to my image is this line of code "background-image:asset-data-url("good.jpg");" in my CSS

Comment: Can you post how your this part of css file looks like before assets compilation?

Comment: I added what my CSS file looks like. (i'm using bootstrap)

Comment: try changing the line with asset-data-url to `background-image: image-url("good.jpg")`

Comment: You sir, deserve a medal. That has been annoying so much the last few days. Thanks a mil!

Answer (score 0):

You can add free `new relic` addon on heroku and examin deeply what's going on, how your app react to requests.